# How to count number of a pattern in a string of words?

Tags: javascript, string, design-patterns

This is the question

```
Given a dictionary of variable names where each name follows CamelCase notation, print the item containing most words. Please note, abbr, like ID , IP are considered one word. i.e. name IPAddress contains two words, IP and Address
```

singleWordChecking('HelloWorldWideWeb');  the result count should be 4
singleWordChecking('HelloWWW'); the result count should be 2

below are my function on checking single world

```
function singleWordChecking(word) {
  let singleWordCount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (
      word[i].toUpperCase() === word[i] &&
      word[i + 1].toLowerCase() === word[i + 1]
    ) {
      singleWordCount += 1;
      console.log(singleWordCount);
    } else if (
      word[i].toUpperCase() === word[i] &&
      word[i + 1].toUpperCase() === word[i + 1]
    ) {
      return singleWordCount;
    }
  }
  return singleWordCount;
}
```

```
singleWordChecking('HelloWorldWideWeb');
```

```
singleWordChecking('HelloWWW');
```

i try with word[i].toUpperCase() === word[i] for verifying the first letter is capitalized,
then if second letter is lowercase
count + 1

however when the word is 'HelloWWW'
the console shows the error of

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
    at singleWordChecking
```

How do i fix this so that the edge cases can be considering into the function

Comment: `word[i + 1].toLowerCase()` - what happens if there is a uppercase letter at the very end of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are going out of bounds of the array by doing your check for the following letter, you will need to add an extra check for:

```
i + 1 < world.length
```

However, there are a couple of other issues. For one, you are returning the count when you should be incrementing the count for all capital abbreviations, also checking for 2 capital letters in a row is insufficient because abbreviations can be any length, therefore a possible solution is:

```
function singleWordChecking(word) {
  let singleWordCount = 0;
  let isAbbreviation = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (word[i].toUpperCase() === word[i]) {
          if (i + 1 < word.length && word[i + 1].toLowerCase() === word[i + 1]) {
              singleWordCount += 1;
              isAbbreviation = false;
              
              continue;
          }
          
          if (!isAbbreviation) {
              singleWordCount += 1;
          }
          
          isAbbreviation = true;
      }
  }
  return singleWordCount;
}
```

Comment: Up vote as this meets the guidelines of [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/943435)